# Como poder operar adentro de los indices de arreglos en MASM

Tags: masm, assembly

Soy bastante nuevo en macro assembler, en mis clases hemos usado el .386 con los includes windows.inc kernel32.inc masm32.inc masm32rt.inc. Pero ahora con algunos ejercicios he notado que pueden usar los arreglos de esta manera

```
mov ax, [edi + ecx * 2]     ; get number from warray
```

es decir que pueden hacer operaciones adentro de los [ ] y cuando yo lo quiero probar o investigar obtengo muy poca informacion. Asi que mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer funcionar los arreglos de esta manera? Es una libreria? O algo distinto?

Answer (score 0):

Eso se usa sin más. El modo de direcconamiento es más estricto en 16 bits que en 32, pero no es cuestión de librerías ni includes. Hacer esas cuentas es lo habitual al acceder a matrices. Es número de columnas * columna + posición de la fila.

Comment: Ok comprendo la logica, y al parecer masm me deja ensamblarlo pero a la hora de asignarlo me dice "Infracción de acceso al leer la ubicación" (estoy usando visual studio 2017). El codigo que use fue MOV EBX,[EDI + EAX * 1 + Aux3]

Comment: Aux3 es una DoubleWord por que no me dejo usar otro registro.

Answer (score 0):

El resultado de las operaciones que haya entre corchetes tiene que ser una dirección de memoria a la que ese proceso tenga acceso. Ese error lo da porque no lo tiene.